# Embedded Youtube playlist not showing on IOS devices

Tags: ios, ipad, youtube-api, playlist

*Original post edited to add more info and add example link*

I created a YouTube playlist and embedded it into a website using the youtube generated iframe code and it works very well on Windows via all browsers. Example here ...

http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLRvvIcA_sgWo3bMuhjLsoruYMue05LSOK&hl=en_US;showinfo=1

However on iOS devices (tried on ipad3 and iPhone 4) the API only shows the first video and no playlist thumbnails or controls. It allows the videos to play one after another but you have no control over them or cannot select which to play.

I have tried researching this for a couple of days but there does not seem to be a definitive answer. I saw some mention of it maybe 6 months ago that it was being looked at or worked on but I would like to find out if this is still an issue, if it will be addressed or how I could get round it. It would be great to see this working on all operating systems. I also noticed my generated code uses the videoseries?list parameter when previously all I have read about is playlist. I assume this is HTML5 related ? Any help or advice would be great please.

---

It seems that things have moved on a little with playlists on ios devices and I think its nearly there now but not quite. Using the same page above http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLRvvIcA_sgWo3bMuhjLsoruYMue05LSOK&hl=en_US;showinfo=1 which I have not changed since the first post. The playlist works perfectly on windows and initially appears to work ok on IOS via Safari and Chrome. However if you hit the playlist link it displays the list and allows you to play a video but only the first time.  After that if you pause the video and try to use the playlist button again it just shows the play bar or hides it again. The only way to get back to the playlist is to refresh the page which is a pain.  Does anyone have any ideas on this or if it can or will be looked at ?

Thanks Martin

Answer (score 1):

This is simply just something the YouTube team hasn't gotten around to building yet.  The HTML5 player has a UI for playlists, but it's missing some features that are found in the flash player.  Eventually the UI will make it into a mobile version as well.

Comment: Great, thanks for that, its the answer I was hoping for. I'll just load it up as it is and hope it springs into life at some point whilst checking back here for updates.

Comment: If you could select this as a good answer so I could get my reputation points that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE google, include & activate the playlist control & playlist thumbnails in the HTML5Player by default. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15727789/2228853

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5397) at Google.  It's not that it's not something that is not built yet. This functionality was working until around Oct 17, 2013.  The issue has been "filed" by the development team much to the ire of those commenting on the support thread. Apart from the "filed" comment there has been no explanation, comment or eta for a fix announced.